# Mathematical Problem Solving

Tags: algorithms, computability

Will a study of the mathematical proof of a (data structure and algorithm based) problem, when posed as a proposition, highlight peculiar properties of the problem which may help in designing an optimal algorithm?

I think that proofs should yield interesting insights, and therefore can be used in designing algorithms. Since the program is expected to return a *true response* for every input, proof must be, in some way, built into the program. Is there any text I can refer to in this regard which will help in real problem solving?

Answer (score 4):

> Will a study of the mathematical proof of a problem [..], highlight peculiar properties of the problem which may help in designing an optimal algorithm?

Often they do. But not necessarily (unless you're a scholar of [constructivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_(philosophy_of_mathematics))), for example when using the [probabilistic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method) to show that a solution to said problem exists, then the proof will not help you designing any algorithm since it does not give you a construction.

> Since the program is expected to return a true response for every input, proof must be, in some way, built into the program.

That would be nice if it were the case, but often proving correctness (see [formal methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_methods)) of an algorithm is rather difficult and/or a real pain. That said, there *is* such a thing as [proof-carrying code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof-carrying_code) which does exactly that, but the proofs are not given to you for free.